# Which are correct: the centre west or west centre? West central or central west?

Tags: word-usage, word-order, word-difference

In which order are these phrases used to locate an area or a place that is in the centre of a region or country and to the west?

Answer (score 3):

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
D1 D2 D3 D4 D5
E1 E2 E3 E4 E5
```

If the region is represented by this grid, **west central** would refer to C2 and **central west** would refer to C1.

Comment: Then, shall i say "in the east centre" or "in the east central" of California?

Comment: @zenith3: It depends how you want to use it: **east centre** is a noun and **east central** is an adjective.